# How can I add a constructor to a type alias in Julia?

Tags: constructor, julia, type-alias

I have a type `Milkshake`, which contains a `flavor` field. I would like to have another type, `Order`, which simply contains a list of `Milkshake`s; thus, I used a `typealias`.

```
julia> VERSION
v"0.5.1"

julia> type Milkshake
           flavor::String
       end

julia> typealias Order Array{Milkshake, 1}
Array{Milkshake,1}

julia> Order([Milkshake("Chocolate"), Milkshake("Vanilla")])
2-element Array{Milkshake,1}:
 Milkshake("Chocolate")
 Milkshake("Vanilla")
```

I would like to add a constructor to `Order`, though, so that I can initialize an order by simply using `flavor` strings. However, when I try to define a constructor that does this, the *definition* oddly returns the type `Array{Milkshake, 1}`.

```
julia> Order(milkshakes::String...) = Order(map(Milkshake, milkshakes))
Array{Milkshake,1}
```

When run, the following error is produced.

```
julia> Order("chocolate", "vanilla")
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Tuple{Milkshake,Milkshake} to an object of type Array{Milkshake,1}
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Array{Milkshake,1}(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
 in Array{Milkshake,1}(::String, ::String) at ./REPL[3]:1
```

How can I add this constructor to the `Order` `typealias`?

Comment: `Order(milkshakes::String...) = Order(map(Milkshake,[milkshakes...]))` works?

Comment: @DanGetz So *that's* where the error came from! Sorry, I should have noticed what the error was alluding to. Would you mind posting this as an answer? (`collect` might be a better alternative to `[milkshakes...]`, by the way.)

Comment: It was indeed confusing. But perhaps the Order type should wrap around Array{Milkshake}, since redefining the Array constructor could break other things.

Comment: @DanGetz Redefining the `Array{Milkshake, 1}` constructor specifically shouldn't break other things... should it?

Comment: Not sure about breakage, but how about defining `Base.convert(::Type{Milkshake},s::String) = Milkshake(s)`. Now the same constructor with strings works i.e. `Order(["Chocolate","Vanilla"])` because of the way Array initialization works. Feels more Julia style.

Comment: @DanGetz This definitely works, but only in some cases. For example, what if I want `Order("chocolate", 3)` to call a different method that returns an array of three chocolate `Milkshake`s?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139085/discussion-between-dan-getz-and-harrison-grodin).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Order(milkshakes::String...) = Order(map(Milkshake,collect(milkshakes)))` works.

With it defined, an Order can be constructed as follows:

```
julia> Order("Chocolate","Vanilla")
2-element Array{Milkshake,1}:
 Milkshake("Chocolate")
 Milkshake("Vanilla")
```

Comment: `Order(milkshakes::String...) = [Milkshake(shake) for shake in milkshakes]` has better performance, and seems simpler to me.